# Execute a method from all instances of a class

Tags: c#, inheritance

I am designing a base class for TextForms and derived classes for Labels , Fields, Dialogboxes... etc. 
i am using the below code

```
public class TextForm
{
    public void Refresh()
    {
    }
}

public class Label : TextForms
{
    public void Refresh()
    {
    }
}
```

and in my program i am instanciating many Labels .. and somewhere i need to call TextForms.Refresh() which must execute all derived classes instances Refresh() method .

i can't imagine how to do?

Comment: Well you'll need to have some way of referring to all those labels... you can't just find "all instances of a type which have ever been created".

Comment: Basically you will need the references for all your labels and call the method in a loop for every element in this reference-array.

Comment: @JonSkeet maybe he has all of them on a form and has a wrong/bad approach? Possible solution is looping over all labels of a form. OP Could provide context so we could help him improve his coding/and question.

Comment: @Mafii: Yup, if they're all on the same form, that would be doable - basically we don't have enough context at the moment.

Comment: You are confused about inheritance. This can't be done. You need to call Refresh for each Label object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't find all the instances by default. Though, there are a few design patterns that will make it easier for you to do so. There is the [Composite Design Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) Which gives you the ability to add sub components to your components. For example, a Form/Window component will be a container of sub components like Labels and TextFields for example. Then, when you will call Refresh on the container (Form/Window - for example) it can call the `Refresh` on all of it's sub components.

There is also the [Observable Design Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) which let components register for 'events' (not necessarily implemented via .Net's Events). Then when you call the Refresh method on the observer, it will call the Refresh methods of all the observable's that are registered.

Answer (score 1):

In your question, you write **TextForms** so I am assuming that this is an object that is an enumerable of some sort.

Liskows substitution principle dictates that if you have a base class of any kind you can always substitute derived classes for the base class

```
var textForms = new List<TextForm>(); 
textForms.Add(new Label());
textForms.Add(new TextBox());
```

so now you can simply iterate through this list as such:

```
foreach(var textForm in textForms){
  ((TextForm) textForm).Refresh();
}
```

You may have to tweak the example a little to get it working, but that is the general answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Like m102 said it is unpractical if not impossible to find all instances. However, assuming you use a canvas or page to display your labels on, it is possible to get all the labels in that canvas.

```
TextForm tf = new TextForm();
foreach (Control ctrl in yourCanvas.Children.OfType<Label>())
{
tf.Refresh();
}
```

This will retrieve all the controls of type label from the canvas. This will not refresh them all at once.

Note: I do not recommend changing labels that are not visible/onscreen. It would require them to be kept in memory and this is performancewise not advised. Oh and your refresh function has a capital R (This is usually reserved for classes).